# Redirecionamento do Login em diferentes páginas no meu tema Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estou desenvolvendo meu próprio tema de Woocommerce, e agora preciso fazer um redirecionamento após efetuar o login em uma determinada página onde estou usando o formulário de login do Woocommerce.

Para isso adicionei a seguinte função na functions.php

```
if (!is_account_page()) {
    add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'redirect_after_login_cart');
    function redirect_after_login_cart(){
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_page_by_path('finalizar-compra') ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Quero que somente na página login-carrinho, faça o redirecionamento após o login para a página finalizar-compra.
O formulário da minha-conta, continua redirecionando para a página minha-conta.
Do modo que está, todos meus formulários de login do Woocommerce estão redirecionando para a página finalizar-compra. A condicional não está sendo respeitada.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei muito grata.

Comment: Resolvi meu problema, baseado nesse link: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200254/login-redirection-on-different-pages-on-my-theme-woocommerce/37212789#37212789)